# Синхронизация Map

Tags: java

Если из разных потоков в `HashMap` добавляются (только добавляются и не более того) записи, то необходимо ли при этом синхронизировать вызов метода `put`?

На сколько я понимаю, синхронизация могла бы потребоваться, если в один момент времени из разных потоков происходит как запись, так и чтение, и удаление, и прочее подобное, но если же речь идёт лишь о добавлении, то в синхронизации нет необходимости (какая уж разница как записи будут добавлены, меп просто будет в любом случае заполнена), или же есть какие-либо подводные камни?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не совсем так, проблема может возникнуть при добавлении в тот момент, когда будет вычисляться адрес памяти, куда поместить элемент, чтобы связать его с текущей структурой HashMap, таким образом при добавлении 2х элементов одновременно, один из них может затеряться.

Также проблема может возникнуть когда один поток читает адрес, а другой удаляет, может возникнуть ситуация, что будет вычислен адрес для чтения объекта, но в это же время он будет удалён из Map, а следовательно данные станут не валидными.

Если вам нужна многопоточная HashMap, то имеется специальная реализация `ConcurrentHashMap`.